# Recursion - Find matching connections

Tags: python, recursion

I used Recursion to find the matching connection between servers. It's "Ping" and "Tracert" simulator project. I need the path list for 'Tracert'.

Here is the virtual connections:

```
connection_list.append(('facebook.com', 'google.com'))
connection_list.append(('google.com', 'instagram.com'))
connection_list.append(('instagram.com', 'example2.com'))
```

My recursion function:

```
def ping(origin, destination):
    path = origin
    for connect in connection_list:
        if origin in connect:
            if destination in connect:
                print('Ping to server',destination,'sucess')
                visited_list.append((origin, connect[1]))
                path = path +'/'+ connect[1]
                print(path)
                return path
            if connect not in visited_list:
                visited_list.append(connect)
                if connect[0] == origin:
                    path = path  +'/'+ping(connect[1], destination)
                else:
                    path = path +'/'+ ping(connect[0], destination)
                print(path)
    return ''
```

When I try to ping:

```
ping('facebook.com', 'example2.com')
```

The results:

```
Ping to server example2.com sucess
instagram.com/example2.com
google.com/instagram.com/example2.com
facebook.com/
```

The expected results:

```
Ping to server example2.com sucess
facebook.com/google.com/instagram.com/example2.com
```

I cannot concatenate `'facebook.com'` to the path. I think there is problem with my recursion function.

Thank you for you time!

Comment: I suggest you modify your `find_next_server()` to just return the path but not print it. Then the caller can do what it wants. This should make it easier to reasona bout what you missed.

Comment: You can add more `print()` statements for debugging purposes. See [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for other tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Please note that simply adding one level of indent to the _first line_ of your code isn't enough to format it for Stack Overflow. This messes with the indentation of your code, since your second line is now at the same level as the first line, and is especially critical for python questions since indentation matters in python. You should either indent the entire block an extra level (select it and click the `{}` button or hit Ctrl+K) or use [code blocks](/help/formatting) by adding three backticks (`) on the lines before and after your code.

Comment: Hi @PranavHosangadi, thanks for your clarifying. I think the code format is ok now? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'd reframe this as a breadth-first search (BFS) on a graph rather than a ping or tracert. In that case, there are ample duplicates and resources online.

Comment: Hi @Code-Apprentice, I have edited the name of the function to Ping(). And I have added 1 more print to debug it, but I cannot find the solution for my recursive function :(

Comment: @ThangTu I suggest adding more prints to see what is going on. This is what I would have to do to figure out the problem for you. As ggorlen mentions, you can read more about breadth first search, too.

Comment: Hi @Code-Apprentice, Thanks for your fast replying. Assume my recurtion is completely wrong. How would you do with the ping function? I don't know if my approach is correct or not.

Comment: @ThangTu I would implement this as a Breadth First Search as mentioned earlier.

Comment: hi @Code-Apprentice, ggorlen, I have applied Breadth First Search techniche and can get the full path. Thank you very much!